# find using regex, in terminal

Tags: regex, find

Using the command bellow:

```
find ./stylesheets/sass/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '[^_].+\.scss'
```

I get this:

```
./stylesheets/sass/_hero.scss
./stylesheets/sass/_article-type.scss
./stylesheets/sass/app.scss
./stylesheets/sass/_footer.scss
./stylesheets/sass/_grid-items.scss
```

and I wanted just:

```
./stylesheets/sass/app.scss
```

so my negation `[^_]` of underscore, does not work beacuse it tries to match at
the very beginning of a path, I suppose, and not the filename itself.

How to solve this, keeping it flexible enough for **any** depth of dirs before
the actual filename?

Comment: No, it's matching 1 character that's not a _, followed by more than one character that can be anything, followed by the extension.

Comment: @Wooble I know what my regex is. That is not my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do it with `-name`:

```
find ... -name '[^_]*.scss'
```

Alternatively, if you insist on using `-regex`, make sure your not-underscore is only in the last component of the pathname:

```
find ... -regex '.*/[^/_][^/]*\.scss$'
```

Comment: great, could you tell me which one of these is more portable?

Comment: The first one is POSIX, the second is not.